# Reading weight from scale with USB cable

Tags: scale, webusb

I have system working in php, I try to get the data from scale TOLEDO S60 , in a Form HTML Using JAVASCRIPT, I try with Web USB API , but does't work

this is my code:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="conectar()">CONECTAR</a>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function conectar(){

        navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId:'0eb8' }] })
        .then(device => {
          console.log(device.productName);      
          console.log(device.manufacturerName); 
        })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); });


    }
</script>
```

I got this response from Chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZyTK.png)

this is the Scale Information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOOms.png)

this is the scale webpage --> https://www.mt.com/us/en/home/phased_out_products/Transport_and_Logistics_Solutions/postal_scales_transp_log/PS_family_transp_logistic/PS60_Scale.html

Comment: My experimentation shows that the vendorId is to be specified in decimal, not in hexadecimal. However, it seems only certain types of devices can be connected in this way, but I do not know why.

Comment: I tried with  decimal values and does not work...

Comment: Try removing the filter completely. You will probably see that some devices are accessible, but the scales you'd like to talk to aren't. Somehow only few devices are available to this library. I do not know why and if anything can be done with it.

Comment: does not work without filters , I tried already

Comment: When I tried `filters: [{  }]` on my notebook, it did find some devices, but not all of them, only a few.

Comment: now a I got all the device , but  I can not see my USB HID

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The `vendorId` filter expects an integer rather than a string. Remove the single quotes and call `requestDevice` like this,

```js
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x0eb8 }] })
```

Comment: I did it , still is not working , doe not detect the device

Comment: Visit chrome://device-log and make sure that the device appears there.

Comment: Yes , is there :   \\?\usb#vid_0eb8&pid_f000#66545176#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} is HidUsb